# How to add snow to this tikz drawing of a mountain?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I edited [Elena Botoeva's tikz example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/sunset/) to draw a mountain.  Here's what it looks like:

[image: mountain drawing]

The picture is intended to be more symbolic than realistic.

Here's the LaTeX/tikz code for drawing it:

```
\documentclass[crop,margin=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[brown,draw=black]
    decorate [decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}]%
    {(0,0) -- (0.5,0.6) -- (1,2) -- (1.5,0.6) -- (2,0)}%
    -- (2,-0.7) -- (0,-0.7) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

*Question*: How can I turn this into a snow-peaked mountain?

I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

I've used the `mountain` path for clipping, another decorated path for the snow and a plain brown rectangle for not snowed mountain.

```
\documentclass[crop,margin=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw[clip]
    decorate [decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}]%
    {(0,0) -- (0.5,0.6) -- (1,2) -- (1.5,0.6) -- (2,0)}%
    -- (2,-0.7) -- (0,-0.7) -- (0,0);
    \fill[brown](0,-.7) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[white]
    decorate [decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}]%
    {(.75,2) -- (0.85,1.5) -- (0.92,1.2) -- (0.99,1.7) -- (1.05,1.4) -- (1.3,2)}%
    -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```